# Macro to delete rows if cell begins with specific number

Tags: vba, excel

I'm looking for a macro which can delete the entire row if cells in a column begins with a specific number.

For example, I want the macro to delete entire row if the cells in column A begins with number 4 or 3

```
Col A
4563 - Delete
3598 - Delete
4598 - Delete
9582
8574
7585
3254 - Delete
```

Appreciate your help!

Regards
Simmy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For `Column A` (excluding first row for header)...

```
Option Explicit

Sub Delete_3_4()

Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

Dim SearchRange As Range, SearchCell As Range, DeleteMe As Range
Set SearchRange = ws.Range("A2:A" & ws.Range("A" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)

For Each SearchCell In SearchRange
    If Left(SearchCell, 1) = 3 Or Left(SearchCell, 1) = 4 Then
        If DeleteMe Is Nothing Then
            Set DeleteMe = SearchCell
        Else
            Set DeleteMe = Union(DeleteMe, SearchCell)
        End If
    End If
Next SearchCell

If Not DeleteMe Is Nothing Then DeleteMe.EntireRow.Delete

End Sub
```

Comment: You could speed this up by putting a filter on Column A and then sorting by values so all of your rows to-be-deleted (`DeleteMe`) are grouped together. You can do this in macro or just sort data before running macro

Comment: Hi,Can i ask you another question, what if i want to have the opposite scenario where i want to delete rows where cell number doesn't begin with 4 or 3?